# Search for all strings that have a space in between using SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Take for example I have entries like 'Jhon Abraham','Hrithik Roshan' and 'Jimmy'.

Then, the output should fetch me the first two entries i.e. 'Jhon Abraham' and 'Hrithik Roshan'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT col_name FROM table_name WHERE col_name LIKE '% %';
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT columnName
FROM table
WHERE trim(columnName) LIKE '% %'
```